# How to change the background color of a custom Collection View cell in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCollectionViewCell

    //let imageView = UIImageView()
    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00)

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00).cgColor

   //cell.placeLabel.tintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00).cgColor

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true

    print("places\(indexPath.row)")
    //cell.placeLabel.text = places[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.placeLabel.text = places[indexPath.row]
    cell.placeLabel.textColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCollectionViewCell

    if (indexPath.row == 0){

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00)

    }
}
```

I created a custom `collectionViewCell`. When I click one of the cell it's `backgroundColor` should change. How can I achieve this?

I have tried it in `didSelectItemItamAt indexpath` method but its not working. Please help.

Comment: didItemSelectpath method will call or not?

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya No it's not calling

Comment: make sure yourCollectionView.allowsSelection = true then it will call didItemSelectpath

Comment: @RakeshMohan Have you try my solution?

Comment: @NiravD It's working. Thank you

Comment: @NiravD I have one more query. I have added an imageview to the cell. Now I need to display that image only on the cell which I select. I would be glad if you help me i this one too. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`selectedBackgroundView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620138-selectedbackgroundview) property of `UICollectionViewCell` for that, inside `cellForItemAt indexPath` set that property and now when you select cell it will automatically change the `backgroundColor` of that cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCollectionViewCell
     //Your other code

     //Add code to set selectedBackgroundView property
     let view = UIView(frame: cell.bounds)
     // Set background color that you want
     view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00) 
     cell.selectedBackgroundView = view
     return cell
}
```

Using this now there is no need to change `backgroundColor` of cell in `didSelectItemAt indexPath` it will work automatically and change `backgroundColor` for that selected cell.

Comment: I think its not the correct way to do this. Why we are allocating a waste memory here for UIView?? Because we can do this without allocating a UIView.

Comment: @DheerajD It is the best way to handle what OP want, have you ever try before posting here comment, also in your code you are just changing the color of cell what about reused of cell that op is doing when collectionView scroll it will change the backgroundColor of some other cell instead of selected one also you haven't remove the backgroundColor when the cell is deselect.

Comment: Nirav yes i did not run the code because i have fixed one of my same issue some time before. Again not agree with you that for the sack of changing background color why should i alloc UIView? As you said after scroll it will change the color so it is right it will. i what answer is according to its current issue not for the whole feature.

Comment: @DheerajD If you doesn't know how things work then just leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your `cellForItemAt` or `didSelectItemAt`

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCollectionViewCell

if (indexPath.row == 0){

cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00) 
cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00) 
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPath)

}
```

}

Comment: I have to write the above code in if(indexpath.row) condition right?

Comment: I need to implement this when I click on the collection view cell.